# SUBSTRING in MYSQL without knowing the length

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field value

```
"An essay is, generally, a piece of writing that gives the author's own argument, but the definition is vague,<img src="mnq.com"> overlapping with those of a letter<img src="xyz.abc">, a paper, an article, a pamphlet, and a short story."
```

I want to fetch all `<img src="">` and replace it with `""` from the string collection. How can I write a SQL in MYSQL.

Comment: Please explain what this means:  *I want to fetch all and replace it with "" from the string collection.*. Sample data and desired results *as text tables* are a big help.

Comment: you can try using regexp_replace() for this. Added this link for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: In output I want this: "An essay is, generally, a piece of writing that gives the author's own argument, but the definition is vague, overlapping with those of a letter, a paper, an article, a pamphlet, and a short story."

Comment: Input : An essay is, generally, a piece of writing that gives the author's own argument, but the definition is vague,<img src="mnq.com"> overlapping with those of a letter<img src="xyz.abc">, a paper, an article, a pamphlet, and a short story.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
 "An essay is, generally, a piece of writing that gives the author's own argument, but the definition is vague,<img src="mnq.com"> overlapping with those of a letter<img src="xyz.abc">, a paper, an article, a pamphlet, and a short story."
,'<img src=".*">','',1,0,'c');
```

Comment: It says not a built-in function. I guess in MYSQL REGEXP_REPLACE doesn't work.

Comment: @dibyajyotisahoo I think it works only for mysql version 8 or later

Comment: Is any other solution possible?